# PHP Resend Verification Email

Tags: php, login-script

I am trying to add a resend verification action to my login/register system using `tampus login system`. I am following [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/16/php-login-system-reloaded-v1-1/).

Comment: What is the error your are facing ? What have you tried so far ? Provide more information on this problem so that people can help you in solving ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay I am not a fan of php frameworks so I will make this one for you with MySQL:

```
if(empty($_POST["user"]) || empty($_POST["pass"])){
    echo "Missing values";
} else {
  //You would need the mysql connection variable named $db_conn
  $db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name");
  $user = $_POST["user"];
  $pass = md5($_POST["pass"]);//MD5 encrypt;

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'"
  $query = mysqli_query($db_conn,$sql);
  if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1){
    //Do the login thingys like cookies and redirects
  } else {
    echo "Check your credentials";
  }
}
```

I think I could not made it easier and better to understand

Comment: You're mixing both MySQL_ and MySQLi_

Comment: There is not problem with them. I have scripts just like this one.

Comment: If you have any doubts don't doubt to tell them to me :3

Comment: Please give the check button some love

Comment: So much wrong here. `md5` shouldn't be used for password hashing. `$_POST['user']` is used directly in SQL leaving it completely open to SQL injection vulnerabilities and thus a hacked site. You can't use `mysqli_` functions with (deprecated!) `mysql_` functions.

Comment: If you are using php 5.3 is perfectly fine, if you want o update to mysqli functions do it, but it works, MD5 is not the safiest encryption method but you can make your own algorithm, and what vulnerabilities?

Comment: @FedericoPiragua I'm not paying anyone who doesn't know what SQL injection is. That's a very, very basic and critical web dev skill.